# Optimizing a mysql query to fetch "unseen" entries per user

Tags: mysql, node.js, optimization

This title is rather mesmerizing but I couldn't come up with something clearer.

Long story short, we're creating a mobile app connected to a node.js server communicating with a mySql database. Pretty common setup. Now, we have multiple users connected that are able to upload "moments" to our servers. These moments can be only seen once by all other users.

As soon as a user x sees another user y's moment, x cannot see this one y's moment, ever. Maybe a bit like Snapchat, except the moment is single user to multiple users instead of single to single. Moments are also ordered by distance according to the current user's location.

Now, I'm looking for an intelligent way of only fetching the "unseen" moments from database. For now, we're using a relational table between Users and Moments.

Let's say a user (ID = 20) sees a moment (ID = 30320), then we insert into this table 20 and 30320. I know. This is hardly scalable and probably a terrible idea.

I thought about maybe checking the last seen date and only fetching moments that are past this date, but again, moments are ordered by distance before being ordered by date so it is possible to see a moment that is 3 minutes old followed by a moment that is 30 seconds old.

Is there a more clever way of doing this, or am I doomed to use a relationship table between Moments and Users, and join to it when querying?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT -**

This logic uses in total 3 tables.

- Users
- Moments
- MomentSeen

MomentSeen only contains what user has seen what moment, and when. Since the moments aren't ordered by date, I can't fetch all the moments that were uploaded after the last seen moment.

**EDIT -**

I just realized the mobile app Tinder must use similar logic for which user "liked" which other user. Since you can't go back in time and see a user twice, they probably use a very similar query as what I'm looking for.

Considering they have a lot of users, and that they're ordered by distance and some other unknown criteria, there must be a more clever way of doing things than a "UserSawUser" relational table.

**EDIT**

I can't provide the entire database structure so I'll just leave the important tables and some of their fields.

```
Users { 
    UserID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
}

Moments {
    MomentID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    UploaderID INT UNSIGNED, /* FK to UserID */
    TimeUploaded DATE /* usually NOW() while insertion */
} 

MomentSeen {
    /* Both are FK to Users and Moments */
    MomentID INT UNSIGNED,
    UserID INT UNSIGNED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider implementing bloom filter. It is widely used to reduce disk seeks and drive better performance.

[Medium](http://www.medium.com) is using it to check if a user has read a post already.

More details here- 
 
https://medium.com/the-story/what-are-bloom-filters-1ec2a50c68ff
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use one table per user.  *Do* have a single table for the moments.

You seem to have two conflicting orderings for "moments":  'distance' and 'unseen'; which is it?

If it is 'unseen', are the 'moments' numbered chronologically?  This implies that each user has a `last_moment_seen` -- all `Moments` before then have been seen; all after that have not been seen.  So...

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE moment > ( SELECT last_moment_seen
                        FROM Users WHERE user_id = $user_id );
```

would get all the moments not yet seen for a given user.

Munch on that for a while; the come back for more suggestions.

**Edit**

This should give you the Moments not yet seen.  You can then order them as you see fit.

```
SELECT m....
    FROM Moments m
    LEFT JOIN MomentSeen ms  ON ms.MomentID = m.MomentID
    WHERE ms.MomentID IS NULL
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 1   -- if desired
```

Comment: I actually already have a table for the moments, a table for the users, and a table which contains the ID of a User and the ID of a moment. This is where I stored which user saw which moment. Since the moments aren't ordered by date but first by distance, it is possible to see a moment that was uploaded after another one first.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I am confused on some things.  I hope that the solution will be with `SELECT ... WHERE a > b ORDER BY c`.  I think `b` comes from `Users`.

Comment: I added what's to be used in the third edit of the question. Thanks Rick.

Comment: Are there N rows in `MomentsSeen` per user?  Will `MomentID` suffice for delineating 'seen' from 'unseen'?  Or do we need to look at `TimeUploaded`?

Comment: TimeUploaded is taken in consideration for ordering, but is not the main condition. It is the second filter. The moments are first ordered by some other algorithm, then filtered by time. MomentsSeen is N to N.

Answer (score 0):

Why hesitate on using join?
Have you try to fill your database with dummy data. million of them to be able to measure performance impact on your system?

Using joins is not such a bad idea and is often faster than a single table, if done right.

You should probably do a research on database design to provide some reference.

For instance, ordering a table is done using an index. 
However, you could use more than one index on one table and a combination of column in each index.
This can be done by analyzing the query(s) often used against the table. 
A handy recipe is by creating index containing a set of column used in join keys, another index for each possible "where" parameter combination as a set of column index, and a set of index column(s) for each "order" query run against that table (the ascending / descending order did matter).

So don't be shy to add another column and index to suit your need.

If you talking about scalability, then you should consider tuning the database engine. 
eg.  make a higher possible key using big integer. 
     using a database cluster setup would also require to do in depth analysis, because autoincrement keys have issue in a multiple master setup

If you try to squeeze more performance from your system, then you should consider designing the whole database to be table partition friendly from the very start. That will include serious analysis of your business rule. Creating a table partition friendly environment  require  setting up a series of column as key, and splitting the data physically (remember to set file_per_table = 1 on mysql config, otherwise the benefit of table partitioning is lost) 
If not done right, however, partitioning will not do any benefit to you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html